# Wrapping Text and Filling Grey Space

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to wrap text on my "`FYI`" column, while maintaining a "`.Fill`" method for the entirety of the `DataGridView`. The problem is, the text will wrap but the width of the `DataGridView` is cut in 1/4 and not taking up the rest of the screen. Any combination of adjustments I make seems to either prevent wrapping from taking place, or expanding the width of the "`Active`" column which never contains more than 3 characters (so I end up with a lot of white space):

```
oCon2 = New SqlConnection
oCon2.ConnectionString = My.Forms.MainForm.GlobalConString
dsFYI = New DataSet
daFYI = New SqlDataAdapter("Select ID, FYI, Active from [Patient_Information].[dbo].[FYI] where [Active] <> 'No' or [Active] is null", oCon)
Dim builder2 As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(daFYI)
builder2.QuotePrefix = "["
builder2.QuoteSuffix = "]"

Try
    daFYI.FillSchema(dsFYI, SchemaType.Source, "FYIGrid")
    daFYI.Fill(dsFYI, "FYIGrid")
    tblFYI = dsFYI.Tables("FYIGrid")
    dataGridView1.DataSource = tblFYI       
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Something has gone wrong..." & vbNewLine & ex.Message)

Finally
    dataGridView1.Columns("ID").Visible = False
    DataGridView1.Columns("FYI").DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
End Try
```

Any help would be awesome

[image: https://imgur.com/CePhTuF]
[image: https://imgur.com/mnznDLQ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of filling your grid in the normal manner:

```
Me.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
```

Try *just* filling your grid with the target column after the data has been bound.

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(ByVal sender As Object, _ 
    ByVal e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) _ 
    Handles dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete

    Me.dataGridView1.Columns("FYI").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    Me.dataGridView1.Columns("FYI").DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.[True]
    Me.dataGridView1.Columns("Active").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
    Me.dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells

End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of wrapped column filling grid]

Comment: Thank you. This works absolutely flawlessly. Kudos, sir.